# Prevent text selection from 'jumping' to top when dragging over whitespace in pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I'm using pdf.js with text selection.

So pdf.js creates a bunch of absolute positioned divs containing the various text from the pdf to supply text selection.

While dragging to select the text, the selection jumps to selecting everything to the top of the text, if you continue your selection into areas that are not text (like areas between paragraphs).

If you go to their example you can see what I'm describing. Try selecting text over several paragraphs in the left column and you'll see the selection "flicker" to selecting everything to top.
http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/web/viewer.html

Any ideas on how to prevent this from happening? It is very distracting.

I think it has something to do with all of the divs holding the text being absolute.

Comment: Hey! I'm looking for a similar fix to PDF.js. Were you ever able to find something to improve this selection issue? Crocodoc handles this by wrapping grouped text in a div and generally works well, but I haven't seen an implementation of this for PDF.js (just a lot of talk about it). Thanks!

Comment: i also going through similar issue .Any resolutions ?

Comment: sorry for the late response.
It's kind of lame, but what I ended up doing was creating empty divs between large gaps of text. 

This way, the selection is usually over some absolutely positioned div. It seems to work reasonably well.

Comment: see also https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/pull/6663

Answer (score 1):

Fixed:
just add height:200px to

```
.textLayer > div {height:200px;}
```

in viewer.css

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit old but still might be useful for some people. Setting `textLayerMode` to 2 should fix that issue.

Example:

```
new PDFViewer({ ...otherProps, textLayerMode: 2 })
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `pdf.js` file, search for `function appendText` and add

```
textDiv.className = "hitext";
```

below

```
var textDiv = document.createElement('div');
```

Now add this to your custom js file:

```
window.addEventListener('mousedown', function mouseup(evt) {

if($(".hitext:hover").length==0) //To check if the cursor is hovering over the text
{
  //Selection is disabled using CSS if the mousedown event was triggered when the cursor was not over the text
  $(".hitext").css({"-webkit-touch-callout": "none", "-webkit-user-select": "none", "-khtml-user-select": "none", "-moz-user-select": "none", "-ms-user-select": "none", "user-select": "none"}); 
}
else 
{
  $(".hitext").css({"-webkit-touch-callout": "text", "-webkit-user-select": "text", "-khtml-user-select": "text", "-moz-user-select": "text", "-ms-user-select": "text", "user-select": "text"}); 
}

});
```